# Restrict "Find My" on kids' iPad

Tags: ios, find-my-iphone, ipados

Is there any way to restrict access to the Find My app on my kids' iPads? I'm concerned about the possibility of precocious six-year-olds marking their parents' devices as lost or remote wiping them.

Comment: Are you using parental controls on those devices?

Comment: @fsb yes I am using parental controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took some time to research this.  It doesn't appear that you can disable 'Find My' using the [Apple Parental Controls](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304).

It seems strange to me that this isn't possible but I couldn't find any authoritative way to prevent changes in this app.

Using the regular Parental Controls on your child's iPad allows you to prevent changes to many system settings and apps so I would recommend doing that, at a minimum.  Also, there might be 3rd-party apps that provide more granular control, for a price, but that's a space that I don't know much about.